TIBCO_BW_6.5.1 - obtain an image as a response of a rest service with GET method
I have designed a rest application with the GET method that retrieves an image in base64 and sends it to the reply, to then obtain the image in jpeg format in response.
In the reply I receive the image in binary format and in the header I have the Content-type set to image/*.
When I call the application via postman I get the error 500 request failed.
Do you have an idea on how to resolve this situation?
Thanks in advance

Can you give more details about the request, the issue might be with the input data.
In Base64 String Validation: Ensure it’s valid and decodable.
Correct MIME Type: Set Content-Type: image/jpeg (not image/*).
